# How do I check if one message is followed by another in AWS Log Insights using query patterns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Can you write a query for AWS Log Insights that would check 2 messages at a time?

What i am looking for is a pattern, where:
message like /text1/ is followed by
message like /text2/

can you have a query that will check for something like
parse (message like text1 and message+1 like text2) as event
stats count(event)

An example would be:
"Info: API request for"
followed by next message:
Error: Invalid

This would allow me to count how many times a particular user made a request, that resulted in a particular error.

sorry for really bad syntax, it's a theory question, not sure if it's possible to do it.
I appreciate all the help.

I have managed to count the specific errors, but was unable to tie them to a specific user, because the error and user are not logged in within the same log message.

Comment: Generally not, that is not how Log Insights work, no. You always need all the relevant information in a single log statement / line / entry.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. I was hoping that someone might have come up with a workaround for this, and i could run the search retrospectively, rather than having to amend the log and wait for data to populate. Thank you for helping anyway!